# Do I need a visa for 5 hours in Ireland?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, ireland, peruvian-citizens

I have a Peruvian passport going from USA to Belgium but landing in Ireland for 5 hours... do I need a visa for 5 hours? Airport said I don't but I want to make sure

Comment: Do you have a single booking all the way from the USA to Belgium, or is it 2 flights booked separately?

Comment: See https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/

Comment: No, you do not need a visa to transit through Ireland if you have a Peruvian passport and your connecting flight is within 24 hours. You will need to have your passport stamped by immigration when you arrive in Ireland, but you will not need to apply for a visa.

Comment: @pujadev Why would the passport be stamped in Ireland? It isn't part of the Schengen. area. I have transited through Dublin and all they did is check the passport, not stamp it.

Answer (score 2):

If and only if you arrive at terminal 2 between 04:00-16:00 AND have a single booking with a same-day connection, then you can transfer without entering the country (you'll still clear "transfer immigration")
Otherwise you need a visa

Comment: In addition, the OP's departing flight must leave DUB on the same calendar day.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Edited